# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' - BeautifulShop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have a little code for **scraping** info from fbref (link for data: https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats) and it worked well but now I have some problems with some features (I've checked that the fields which don't work now are"player","nationality","position","squad","age","birth_year"). I have also checked that the fields have the same name in the web that it used to be. Any ideas/help to solve the problem?

Many Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import sys, getopt
import csv

def get_tables(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    ## The next two lines get around the issue with comments breaking the parsing.
    comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("",res.text),'lxml')
    all_tables = soup.findAll("tbody")
    team_table = all_tables[0]
    player_table = all_tables[1]
    return player_table, team_table

def get_frame(features, player_table):
    pre_df_player = dict()
    features_wanted_player = features
    rows_player = player_table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows_player:
        if(row.find('th',{"scope":"row"}) != None):
    
            for f in features_wanted_player:
                cell = row.find("td",{"data-stat": f})
                a = cell.text.strip().encode()
                text=a.decode("utf-8")
                if(text == ''):
                    text = '0'
                if((f!='player')&(f!='nationality')&(f!='position')&(f!='squad')&(f!='age')&(f!='birth_year')):
                    text = float(text.replace(',',''))
                if f in pre_df_player:
                    pre_df_player[f].append(text)
                else:
                    pre_df_player[f] = [text]
    df_player = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pre_df_player)
    return df_player

stats = ["player","nationality","position","squad","age","birth_year","games","games_starts","minutes","goals","assists","pens_made","pens_att","cards_yellow","cards_red","goals_per90","assists_per90","goals_assists_per90","goals_pens_per90","goals_assists_pens_per90","xg","npxg","xa","xg_per90","xa_per90","xg_xa_per90","npxg_per90","npxg_xa_per90"]

def frame_for_category(category,top,end,features):
    url = (top + category + end)
    player_table, team_table = get_tables(url)
    df_player = get_frame(features, player_table)
    return df_player

top='https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/'
end='/Premier-League-Stats'
df1 = frame_for_category('stats',top,end,stats)

df1
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t write all code. I have updated now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you be more specific (show us the error, show us which line doesn't work ...)

Comment: FYI the correct term is ‘scraping’. Scrapping means throwing away as in rubbish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only after the player stats, change `player_table = all_tables[1]` to `player_table = all_tables[2]`, because now you are feeding team table into `get_frame` function.

I tried it and it worked fine after that.

Comment: Many thanks! It finally worked with that change. For futures ocasions what does that number refer?

Comment: Well, this `all_tables = soup.findAll("tbody")` gives you a list of "tbody" elements that were found, so the number in this case is just a reference to a specific "tbody" element.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest loading the table with panda's [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). There is a direct link to this table under Share & Export --> Embed this Table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=fb&url=%2Fen%2Fcomps%2F9%2Fstats%2FPremier-League-Stats&div=div_stats_standard", header=1)
```

This outputs a list of dataframes, the table can be accessed as `df[0]`. Output `df[0].head()`:

|  | Rk | Player | Nation | Pos | Squad | Age | Born | MP | Starts | Min | 90s | Gls | Ast | G-PK | PK | PKatt | CrdY | CrdR | Gls.1 | Ast.1 | G+A | G-PK.1 | G+A-PK | xG | npxG | xA | npxG+xA | xG.1 | xA.1 | xG+xA | npxG.1 | npxG+xA.1 | Matches |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Patrick van Aanholt | nl NED | DF | Crystal Palace | 30-190 | 1990 | 16 | 15 | 1324 | 14.7 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.07 | 0.07 | 0 | 0.07 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 0.8 | 2 | 0.08 | 0.05 | 0.13 | 0.08 | 0.13 | Matches |
| 1 | 2 | Tammy Abraham | eng ENG | FW | Chelsea | 23-156 | 1997 | 20 | 12 | 1021 | 11.3 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.53 | 0.09 | 0.62 | 0.53 | 0.62 | 5.6 | 5.6 | 0.9 | 6.5 | 0.49 | 0.08 | 0.57 | 0.49 | 0.57 | Matches |
| 2 | 3 | Che Adams | eng ENG | FW | Southampton | 24-237 | 1996 | 26 | 22 | 1985 | 22.1 | 5 | 4 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.23 | 0.18 | 0.41 | 0.23 | 0.41 | 5.5 | 5.5 | 4.3 | 9.9 | 0.25 | 0.2 | 0.45 | 0.25 | 0.45 | Matches |
| 3 | 4 | Tosin Adarabioyo | eng ENG | DF | Fulham | 23-164 | 1997 | 23 | 23 | 2070 | 23 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0.1 | 1.1 | 0.04 | 0.01 | 0.05 | 0.04 | 0.05 | Matches |
| 4 | 5 | AdriÃ¡n | es ESP | GK | Liverpool | 34-063 | 1987 | 3 | 3 | 270 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Matches |

Comment: Good point! Many thanks for the quick answer